# How to use double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following:

```
var child = require('child_process');
var res = child.execSync("df -l | awk '{t += $2} END {printf "%d G\n", t / 2^20 + 0.5}'");
```

I'm getting a syntax error (the `"` in `printf` are at fault here).

I tried to escape using `\"`, to no avail.

Using: `"df -l | awk '{t += $2} END {printf \"%d G\n\", t / 2^20 + 0.5}'"`.

I get:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {t += $2} END {printf "%d G
awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ unterminated string
```

What is the syntactically  correct way to proceed here?

Comment: `\"` is the correct way to insert a double quote into a string literal delimited by double quotes. Why does it not work in your case? What's the issue?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you show exactly how you escaped the line with `\"` that is not working?

Comment: BTW current (4.x+) version of node.js supports ES6 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

Comment: @pawel Oh that's interesting. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var res = child.execSync("df -l | awk \'{t += $2} END {printf \"%d G\\n\", t / 2^20 + 0.5}\'");`

works, tested.

The problem was with `\n`. It should be `\\n`. You can debug any shell task like this:
`console.log(SHELL_COMMAND)`
and then mannually run output string.

For example, this:

```
var child = require('child_process');
var cmd = "df -l | awk '{t += $2} END {printf \"%d G\n\", t / 2^20 + 0.5}'";
console.log(cmd)
var res = child.execSync(cmd);
```

will output in console and try to run this:

```
df -l | awk '{t += $2} END {printf "%d G
", t / 2^20 + 0.5}'
```

which makes no sense.

Comment: Good call on escaping the `\n`.  I don't think you need to escape the `'`, do you?

Comment: @RocketHazmat well, actually, there is no need to escape `'` here. You can test any variants using method that I described in answer

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to escape the `\n`. Thanks !

Comment: Usually you have to escape the single quote only if your string is opened/closed with it. Same for double quotes. ' ' ' needs to be ' \' ', " ' " is fine, " " " needs to be " \" " and ' " ' is fine.